# Add components dynamically on click React + Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to learn React and now i'm building a simple Events Scheduler similar to [React-big-scheduler](https://github.com/StephenChou1017/react-big-scheduler). I'm using Redux to store the positions of each cell. Basically what I'm trying to do is when I click on a cell, in that position should render a [React-rnd component](https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd) based on cell position and size(pretty much cover all cell) which can be resized or dragged to another position later.

As far as I understand the problem is when rendering elements in the Scheduler component. Any ideea is much appreciated.

[Full code and demo here)](https://codesandbox.io/s/64qm3nl54r) (I know it has some bugs at display but for now i only want to render the element when clicked)

Comment: well, not sure about that because you don't paste all your code, but normaly, you should dispatch an action to follow the redux lifecycle. does you addCellProp dispatch an action ? can you paste your action and your reducer ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your reducer, how are you hardcoding the values? You should put them as initial state in your reducer like this:

`const reducer = (state = hardCodedValues, action) => {}`

Add the code for your reducer and it might be easier to see the problem.

**Edit after seeing codesandbox:**

As others have said, it seems like there is some very unpure logic in your reducer. You are directly modifying the state by using .push on your cellProps array instead of returning a new one. There are also many conditional statements in your reducer cases which makes the whole state very unpredictable. As far as I understand it seems like your ADD_CELL_PROP actions don't update the state well, it only gets updated from UPDATE_CELL_PROP actions.

I would recommend removing all of the resize logic and get the pure part of the system working. Resizing and dragging are very dom-based events which can be tricky to handle with Redux, so add them only after you're sure to have the desired behaviour working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using document.getElementById with React. If anything you would use a ref (learn more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), however in this case you need neither. You should have the "cellClick" method in your Scheduler component and be passing it to your `<Test/>` component with the cellProps.

Ex: `<Test onClick={(e) => cellClick(e, props)} key={cellProp.id}/>`

id's are not needed in react as DOM elements are not retrieved this way. A key value is only required and that is only when a array of components are used. Look into the onClick prop as you need to pass this to a clickable component.

Comment: From the code above it does not appear Redux is being used correctly. I would recommend learning base React before taking on Redux. I did base React for a few months before learning Redux.

Comment: I used `document.getElementById` only to get the absolute position of cell by using `getBoundingClientRect()` because i got errors with ref.